# Microsoft. ReportingServices.ProcessingCore not found

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to add a third party reporting chart control in to my project. I'm using visual studio 2005 and i've installed SQL Server 2005 along with the Reporting Services. When i try to add the third party dll to the tool box, i get the error message

---

'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

---

I checked out the assembly and i was not able to find any dlls starting with Microsoft.ReportingServices.

Any ideas?

Thank you

NLV

Comment: Okie i found the DLLs in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin. But why is not in the GAC? Can i just add all the DLLs to the GAC?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a bit late, but I wanted to share something I learned for future possibilities of this error for others.  I experienced a similar issue after some software was installed that appears to have updated SQL for VS and/or SQL assemblies in general.  It appears this caused a mismatch of what assembly SSRS was trying to use vs what it could find.

I found the following workaround:
You can go to the appropriate `reportserver` bin and add/replace the `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore.dll` with the appropriate version one.  The location for this bin is

> Drive(ex. C):\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS__.MSSQLSERVER(or
>   whatever report server name is)\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin.

I just copied the `.dll` here and then went to Reporting Services Configuration and stopped and re-started the report server.

Answer (score 0):

If there is enough disk space on the DB server but this message still appears, restart the SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER) service